# Smarthome AOG. The best way (in 2021) to integrate state of devices with firestore fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have this project: https://github.com/neuberfran/firebasefunction/blob/main/firebase/functions/smart-home/fulfillment.js
It works well. But, for example, I want to implement a condition that if I have the garage closed and I said "close garage", the Home assistantt will alert me about it.

As shown in the photo below, I am using an **rpi3/iot-device/back-end** that controls the **garagestate** field.
I need to know the best way to implement this condition, that is, read the value of the **garagestate** field and from that, know if I can open the garage or not:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably need to add an intermediary condition in your `onExecute` to [return an error](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions) based on the Firestore state:

```js
// ...
for (const target of command.devices) {
    const configRef = firestore.doc(`device-configs/${target.id}`)
    const targetDoc = await configRef.get()
    const {garagestate} = targetDoc.data()
    if (garagestate === false) {
       // garagestate exists and is false
       // return an error
       return {
         requestId,
         payload: {
           status: 'ERROR',
           errorCode: 'alreadyClosed'
         }
       }
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Comment: Tks. But for now I had a regression.The function was deployed without errors. Issue is: "I couldn't find the garage. Please check in the app if this device is fully configured.". This is my new execute intent(I would be grateful if you can help more): https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/d35b02fafb6c6317051caeaaee49cc52

Comment: My `// ...` meant to serve as placeholders. You should continue to use the `batch.update` command, just after the if-statement. This for-loop would replace the forEach you have in your code, but much of what you've done should remain unchanged.

Comment: iwas successful in the first part of my issue. I get error when garagestate=false. But, I went to implement the option && (necessary condition to be added the main condition, because without it all the garage actions freeze when garagestate=false) in the if and I re-locked in the error of my previous answer. How to implement && curExec.command==='action.devices.commands.Close'?
What is the best way to handle the errorCode: 'alreadyClosed' so that I stop getting the screen below and get a voice message on GHome?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuXEcTbDK_U6qVl6xq1U4NmC7Ww8vD-z/view

Comment: My last fulfillment execute intent Code: https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/6a1f21f28a155c5d122ee0e10b99116f

Comment: My code snippet shows that you should read the current fields from Firestore before going forward. You can add other checks to the same conditional. But ultimately you want to return the error the way shown above.

Comment: My last question is: This following code is not working and is not calling the error screen: if (garagestate === false && command === 'action.devices.commands.Close'). If I put 'action.devices.commands.OpenClose', it calls the error screen both when I say open garage and close garage. This is not what I want. I just want the error screen to appear when I say close the garage. How would you help 1 more?https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/8314351f2a3467e7c19cf9b13d400048

Comment: The command name you need to check for is [action.devices.commands.OpenClose](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/openclose#device-commands). You can check the params (`reqCommand.execution[0].params.openPercent`) to see if it's a close or open request, where '0' is 'closed'.

Comment: Tks. That's worked. Only one more think about screen error and not mensage  by voice error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuXEcTbDK_U6qVl6xq1U4NmC7Ww8vD-z/view

Comment: That might be the error you'll get. There's no way for you to customize it.

Comment: I think I can create a error Class like: SmartHomeError: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-traits/#5

Comment: You can create an error on your side, but it won't change the client-side error message.